# array_values recursive php

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, multidimensional-array

Let's say I have an array like this:

```
Array
(
    [id] => 45
    [name] => john
    [children] => Array
    (
        [45] => Array
            (
                [id] => 45
                [name] => steph
                [children] => Array
                    (
                        [56] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 56
                                [name] => maria
                                [children] => Array
                                    (
                                        [60] => Array
                                            (
                                                [id] => 60
                                                [name] => thomas
                                            )

                                        [61] => Array
                                            (
                                                [id] => 61
                                                [name] => michelle
                                            )

                                    )
                            )

                        [57] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 57
                                [name] => luis
                            )

                     )

            )

    )

)
```

What I'm trying to do is to reset the keys of the array with keys `children` to 0, 1, 2, 3, and so on, instead of 45, 56, or 57.

I tried something like:

```
function array_values_recursive($arr)
{
    foreach ($arr as $key => $value)
    {
        if(is_array($value))
        {
            $arr[$key] = array_values($value);
            $this->array_values_recursive($value);
        }
    }

    return $arr;
}
```

But that reset only the key of the first children array (the one with key 45)

Comment: why 'o why people are insisting on working with multiple-levels of nested arrays instead of using OOP ?

Comment: What did you pass into the function, the array or array[children]?

Comment: I passed the array to the function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use a recursive approach but you do not assign the return value of the function call `$this->array_values_recursive($value);` anywhere. The first level works, as you modify `$arr` in the loop. Any further level does not work anymore for mentioned reasons.

If you want to keep your function, change it as follows (untested):

```
function array_values_recursive($arr)
{
  foreach ($arr as $key => $value)
  {
    if (is_array($value))
    {
      $arr[$key] = $this->array_values_recursive($value);
    }
  }

  if (isset($arr['children']))
  {
    $arr['children'] = array_values($arr['children']);
  }

  return $arr;
}
```

Comment: The recursion works but all the keys in my array are changed to 0, 1, etc... (even the keys id and name). I only want the numeric keys in my array with index children to change

Comment: I simply translated your words into PHP now.

Answer (score 4):

```
function array_values_recursive($arr)
{
    $arr2=[];
    foreach ($arr as $key => $value)
    {
        if(is_array($value))
        {            
            $arr2[] = array_values_recursive($value);
        }else{
            $arr2[] =  $value;
        }
    }

    return $arr2;
}
```

this function that implement **array_values_recursive** from array like:

```
array(   
   'key1'=> 'value1',   
   'key2'=> array (              
         'key2-1'=>'value-2-1',
         'key2-2'=>'value-2-2'
          )
);
```

to array like:

```
array(
    0 => 'value1',
    1 => array (
           0 =>'value-2-1',
           1 =>'value-2-2'
          )
);
```

Comment: you should explain your answer

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
function array_values_recursive($arr, $key)
{
    $arr2 = ($key == 'children') ? array_values($arr) : $arr;
    foreach ($arr2 as $key => &$value)
    {
        if(is_array($value))
        {
            $value = array_values_recursive($value, $key);
        }
    }
    return $arr2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this ,

```
    function updateData($updateAry,$result = array()){
     foreach($updateAry as $key => $values){
      if(is_array($values) && count($values) > 0){
        $result[$key] = $this->_updateData($values,$values);
      }else{
        $result[$key] = 'here you can update values';
      }
     }
     return $result;
   }
```

Answer (score -2):

You can used php fnc walk_array_recursive 
[Here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php)

Comment: Please explain how they'd use that to solve their problem.

Comment: I think `walk_array_recursive ` does not walk over the tree, instead walks over leafs. So is unusable in this case.