# How to merge an associative array into a single associative row of a multidimensional array?

Tags: php

I have those two arrays:

```
array1[1]["associativeKey1"]
         ["associativeKey2"]
      [2]["associativeKey1"]
         ["associativeKey2"]
...

array2["associative"]
```

I generate a single array2 for each number in array1, NOT associativeKey, only numbers.
I want to merge those like this:

```
array1[1]["associativeKey1"]["associativeKey2"][content of array2 with all its keys]
      [2]["associativeKey1"]["associativeKey2"][content of array2 with all its keys]
```

Can you help me?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: There is a lot of ways to do that. Why don't you show us a real case scenario? It will be better to explain how to do and why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if I understood correctly, you can call arra-merge for each top level element of array1

```
foreach ($array1 as &$item) {
   $item = array_merge($item, $array2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try to use [array_values](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) (only in the case that isn't recursive)

Comment: for a recursive alternative there's another [answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11943678/array-values-recursive-php)