# Correct image path from an array

Tags: php, arrays, image

I am trying to display an image, where the path is defined in an array **not** from a database.

First `index.php` calls `app/app.php`, which then includes the `$animals` array from `animals.php`.

The problem is how do I access `$animals` in `index.php` and get the value of the `pics` key?

**index.php**

```
<?php require_once __DIR__ . '/app/app.php';
    //var_dump($animals);?>
<?php foreach ($animals as $animal): ?> <br>
    <a href="#"><?php echo $animal['name'] ?></a> 
    <?php echo $animal['size'] ?>
    <img src="<?php echo $animal['pics'] ?>" alt="Pic 1">
    <?php //echo "<img src='" . $pics . "' alt=''>";  ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

**app/app.php:**

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', '1');
error_reporting('E_ALL');
$animals = require_once __DIR__ . '/Db/animals.php';
```

**animals.php:**

```
<?php

return [
    [
        'name' => 'cow',
        'size' => 20,
        'pics' => ['/photos/cow1.jpg'],
         //'pics' => 'photos/cow1.jpg',
         //'pics' => '<img class="wrap" src="photos/cow1.jpg">',
         //'pics' => './photos/cow1.jpg';
         'detailes' => [
             'colour' => 'brown',
             'origin' => 'N Italy',
         ],
    ],
];
```

It's frustrating that I can't solve it. Maybe someone could help.

Comment: pics is a sub array, so `$animal['pics'][0]` is the first one

Comment: `var_dump` is your friend. Maybe with xdebug for pretty output. Good to get in habit of deciphering those dumps.

Comment: Thanks Smith. I ask you if I defined corectly 'pics' in animals.php?

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps...

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(4) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(3) "cow"
    ["size"]=>
    int(20)
    ["pics"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(16) "/photos/cow1.jpg"
    }
    ["detailes"]=>
    array(2) {
      ["colour"]=>
      string(5) "brown"
      ["origin"]=>
      string(7) "N Italy"
    }
  }
}
```

You actually want: `echo $a[0]['pics'][0];`

Arrays, inside arrays. It does get confusing but will fast become second nature to work with.

Play around with `var_dump`...

```
var_dump($a);
var_dump($a[0]);
etc...
```

or try iterating when stumped...

```
foreach ($a as $key => $value) {
 echo "$key -> $value";
}
```

That would result in `NOTICE Array to string conversion` because `$value` is an array. Try adding a second (nested) foreach loop. When you can iterate over the entire array you know you understand it... see also: [is_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-array.php) and [recursion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11943678/array-values-recursive-php).